# unit testing asp.net web services web methods having direct connection to database

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, nunit

I have a asp.net web services service layer which has [WebMethod]s. Those web methods have connection strings and are modifying dev db. There is no separate data access layer. WebMethods are modifying the db through stored procedure. I want to unit test those web methods using nunit. But could not figure out a way to do it without modifying the db. I am willing to modify my service layer so as to completely separate the data access layer and then unit test it. Any leads towards good practices to do these things will be appreciated.

Update:
My webservice is being used by an established product making it difficult to do constructor dependency injection after separating the DAL.

Comment: Abstract your data access into a repository which inherits from an interface. You can then use that interface to create a mock repo that is testable but does not hit your actual database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution lies directly in the teory of Unit testing. You create a data access layer that implements an inteface and you use Dependency injection to use the real code in running scenarios, and a mocked service for test scenarios.

The code you want to test, you need to isolate from the code above and from the code below. Then for every scenario or method you prepare a test, which will verify if in this test case, for the expected input data, you get expected output data.

Comment: I already have an established layer which is using the web services. If i create a DAL that implements an interface and use Dependency injection, I would have to change the constructor of the service class to make use of it right? So that I can mock the interface when calling from the test class.  I am sorry if I am wrong as I am very new to programming world.

Comment: I would recommend to use a Static service locator, or in this case Data Access locator. The Di is handled in this locator, and you always use the static resource. If you create a general locator using generics, you reuse it for multiple mocking scenarios.

Comment: When you want a ServiceMock, you would get it from the locator, the same if you need the real service. The same with the DAL. The important thing is that you always use the Interface that both versions will implement. Generics will handle this really well

Comment: This solved my problem. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

You definitely have to change your DAL to unit test this. Your unit tests should not touch the database, you should make a repository or some other abstraction, which you can mock in your tests.

Comment: If i create a DAL that implements an interface and use Dependency injection, I would have to change the constructor of the service class to make use of it right? So that I can mock the interface when calling from the test class. I am sorry if I am wrong as I am very new to programming world.

Comment: Yes that sound correct. No matter what, you need some class that takes the interface of the service as a dependecy in the constructor. Then you can mock the service dependency in your test, and test all other code around it.

Comment: I already have an established layer that uses the web services. If i change the constructor to take interface as a parameter, how would i use the web service. I would need to change the code where the service is getting used?

Answer (score 0):

So there are two types of tests I think you may be confusing.  Unit tests are just specific functions that you can test and should not rely on outside systems.  You could perform integration tests since the web service is so tightly coupled with this database though.  It would take refactoring out the DB functions and mocking the calls to it in order to be able to properly test the service.  Once you do that, MSDN has steps on how to properly unit test a web service: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243399(v=vs.100).aspx